# SQL CONVERT not working when WHERE is added

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, numeric, varchar

**Using:** SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, T-SQL

**Description of issue:** I basically have two tables with an `AccountNumber` column. In one table, it is stored as `NUMERIC`, in the other table, it is stored as `VARCHAR` (unfortunately this data type discrepancy cannot be changed).

So for consistency's sake, to get them both into the numeric data type, my attempted solution is to just `LEFT JOIN` in the `VARCHAR` table with the `AccountNumber` column converted to `NUMERIC`.

That works just fine and the query will run.

*However,* as soon as I add a `WHERE` clause to it, it crashes with the error shown below. As you can see, with the `WHERE` clause, I am essentially just making the query search for a specific (`NUMERIC`) `AccountNumber`.

Why would I get this conversion error issue when the `AccountNumber` column coming out of the `LEFT JOIN` is `NUMERIC`?

```
/*
Assumptions:
    A.AFIELD is numeric
    B.BFIELD is varchar

Result:
    Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 10
    Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
*/

SELECT A.AccountNumber, B.AccountNumber
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC, B.AccountNumber) AccountNumber
     FROM B
     WHERE ISNUMERIC(B.AccountNumber) = 1) B ON B.AccountNumber = A.AccountNumber
WHERE A.AccountNumber = 1234567890
/*NOTE: I am searching the originally numeric AccountNumber field for a numeric, yet it's erroring out*/
```

Comment: It is telling you that there is (are) a value(s) in B that cannot be converted to numeric.

Comment: `case when isnumeric() then convert(numeric) end`

Answer (score 1):

you should perform the conversion to `VARCHAR`:

```
select A.AccountNumber, B.AccountNumber
from A
left join
    (
    select AccountNumber
    from B
    where ISNUMERIC(B.AccountNumber)=1
    ) B on B.AccountNumber = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.AccountNumber)
where A.AccountNumber = 1234567890;
```

Comment: Lamak, thank you for your response. For other reasons, it would be preferable to convert B to numeric. Basically this query will be thrown into an Excel Data Connection where endusers will drop a list of numeric AccountNumbers into an Excel column. A VBA script will loop them all together and throw them into the WHERE part of the query and return the results.

Comment: @Chase I don't see the problem, you can use the values as numeric in the `WHERE` condition

Comment: Sorry - to further elaborate, some endusers will be dropping in numerics while others will be dropping in varchars (for example, '01234567890'). It's a little irritating, but it depends on what system of record they are obtaining the AccountNumbers from. So converting to numeric will ensure correct results, while converting to varchar may return correct results. I guess more fundamentally to is simply <i>WHY</i> my query is error-ing out?

Comment: @Chase the conversions suggested by Lamak are used only in the `WHERE` and `ON` clauses. The output (the `SELECT` list) includes both columns, unconverted. So you can use whatever you like for exporting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my comment, "It is telling you that there is (are) a value(s) in B that cannot be converted to numeric" was not clear enough. Try this:

```
select A.AccountNumber, B.AccountNumber
from A
left join
    (
    select CONVERT(numeric,B.AccountNumber) AccountNumber
    from B
    where ISNUMERIC(B.AccountNumber)=1
    ) B on coalesce(B.AccountNumber,0) = A.AccountNumber
where A.AccountNumber = 1234567890;
```

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
  (
    accountnumber NUMERIC
  );
DECLARE @t2 TABLE
  (
    accountnumber VARCHAR(20)
  );

INSERT  @t1 ( [accountnumber] )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 );

INSERT  @t2 ( [accountnumber] )
VALUES  ( '1' ),
        ( '3' ),
        ( 'NonConvertible' );


SELECT  A.accountnumber, B.accountNumber
FROM    @t1 AS [A]
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                CASE 
                    -- Still not 100% safe because ISNUMERIC isn't
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(B.accountnumber) = 1
                    THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC, accountnumber) 
                    ELSE CONVERT(NUMERIC, NULL)
                END AS accountNumber
            FROM    @t2 AS [B]
            WHERE   ISNUMERIC(accountNumber) = 1
--          ) B ON B.accountNumber = A.accountnumber
          ) B ON COALESCE(B.accountNumber, 0) = A.accountnumber
WHERE   A.accountnumber = 1;
```

Comment: I would really ask the downvoter, WHY? Just for satisfaction?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but what makes you think that this will prevent the error from happening?

Comment: Simple enough, error is pointing to it :) That is how MS SQL server works. I find it rude that people simply downvote when they don't understand something.

Comment: I know what the error means, I'm just saying that this doesn't really solve it for every case. For instance, add `'1e1'` to your `@t2` table and see what happens

Comment: @CetinBasoz Not sure who downvoted your answer, but adding in the COALESCE did allow the correct resultant to be returned. But I guess I'm just wondering WHY my query would not work fundamentally? I mean the left join is producing only numerics, so why can I not search (as in WHERE) by a numeric?? It is confounding

Comment: Applying a 'WHERE' filtering there, you are changing the meaning of Left Join and MSSQL attempts to convert each value. You might prevent that moving the where to top, something like:  from (select ... from @t1 .. where a.accountnumer = 1) A left join .... Check execution plans for a better understanding.

Comment: @Lamak, 1e1 would be a problem, yes, and with 2008 I can't think of a simple solution. In 2012, you could simply use the original query with TRY_CONVERT(numeric, accountnumber)